# C++ boost unordered_map - determine if key exists in container

Tags: c++, boost

In `boost::unordered_map` how do I determine if a key exists in it or not?

```
boost::unordered_map<vector<int>, MyValueType> my_hash_map;

if (my_hash_map[non-existent key] == NULL)
```

The above gets compiler error "no match for operator '=='..."

Is the problem that I am using a custom value type or something else?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id3729049-bb) method:

```
if (my_hash_map.find(non-existent key) == my_hash_map.end())
```

Comment: ... like with any standard-compliant containers, by the way.

Comment: I assume so, since unordered_map is a hash table.

Answer (score 26):

`exist()` is spelled [`count()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html#id1505366-bb) for any [associative container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/AssociativeContainer.html):

```
if (my_hash_map.count(key)) { /*key exist*/ }

if (!my_hash_map.count(key)) { /*key does not exist*/ }
```

Comment: Not that usually matters, but I can imagine `count()` being more expensive especially if you have multiple values per key, because it has to actually iterate over all of them.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský: Yes, for `multi_*` containers `count()` can have worse performance than `find()`.

Comment: Depending on the size of `my_hash_map`, one could still prefer the `.count()` method (rather than `.find()`), because it correctly handles the boundary case where `my_hash_map` contains a single key/value(s) pair.

Comment: @Kris, what boundary case? The accepted answer is valid for any contents of `my_hash_map`, including single-entry and empty cases.

Comment: Ah @RomanL you're right, `end` points to [*past-the-last* element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/end).